# Is using Groups to send messages on SignalR is more efficient than sending message to each Connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

On a project with SignalR, I need to sometime send messages to one particular `Connection`, and sometimes send the same message to several `Connections` (from 2 to up to 50).

With the architecture I am using, it is more convenient (from the coding aspect) to, when sending message to several `Connections`, send message to each `Connection` instead of using `Groups`.

I am sure that the best practice is to use the `Group` functionality in this case, but I am asking myself this question:

Does sending message to several `Connections` is less *CPU/Network/etc* consuming using `Groups` than sending a message to each `Connection`? Or does the `group` functionnality is just a convenient way for the developer to send message to several `connections` (and behind the scene, the `groups` are wired to each `connections`)?

Comment: Isn't it likely that Network I/O costs overwhelm any processor performance considerations?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Are you saying that it cost more network to send to each Connection rather thant using Group?

Comment: Network I/O is going costs is going to be your biggest consideration but varies too much based on the content size. Given the performance capability of SignalR, your concern over Group Message vs. Individual User Message is probably not worth worrying about. Either way, it has to go out over the connection out to each client. Also consider this tweet by Damian Edwards about performance - https://twitter.com/damianedwards/status/486655672226816000?lang=en

Comment: In terms of Group vs. User messaging, it comes down to what they offer. If you have 100 users in a group and send a message using Group, you don't have to iterate over every user, whereas with using User your will which will impact CPU performance. The "Network I/O" impact is the same using either but should be your biggest concern because you could bottle neck there depending on the size of the message and how many Users being sent to. But that is relatively moot when you consider the performance tweet I linked.